# for loop for different datasets in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, data-manipulation

you can download the Datasets below, those datasets have common colnames Long/Lat

```
downloadGithubData <- function() {
  download.file(
    url      = "https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/archive/master.zip",
    destfile = "data/covid19_data.zip"
  )
  
  data_path <- "COVID-19-master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_"
  unzip(
    zipfile   = "data/covid19_data.zip",
    files     = paste0(data_path, c("confirmed_global.csv", "deaths_global.csv", "recovered_global.csv", "confirmed_US.csv", "deaths_US.csv")),
    exdir     = "data",
    junkpaths = T
  )
}


updateData <- function() {
  # Download data from Johns Hopkins (https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19) if the data is older than 0.5h
  if (!dir_exists("data")) {
    dir.create('data')
    downloadGithubData()
  } else if ((!file.exists("data/covid19_data.zip")) || (as.double(Sys.time() - file_info("data/covid19_data.zip")$change_time, units = "hours") > 0.5)) {
    downloadGithubData()
  }
}

# Update with start of app
updateData()

#TODO: Still throws a warning but works for now
#DATASETS#
data_confirmed    <- read_csv("data/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv")
data_deceased     <- read_csv("data/time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv")
data_recovered    <- read_csv("data/time_series_covid19_recovered_global.csv")
data_confirmed_us <- read_csv("data/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv")
data_deceased_us  <- read_csv("data/time_series_covid19_deaths_US.csv")
```

using for loop  I want to change all the column names for all the datasets as `'longitude'` and `'latitude'`

```
   colnames(data_confirmed)[colnames(data_confirmed) == 'Long'] <- 'longitude'
    colnames(data_confirmed)[colnames(data_confirmed) == 'Lat'] <- 'latitude'
```

any help will be appreciated,
many thanks in advance,

Comment: Does it have to be a loop? I would stick all the data frames into a list and use `lapply` with an anonymous function.

Comment: lappy works too

Comment: something like this should do: Make a list of all your data frames (e.g., df_list) and then 
`new_df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x){
  colnames(x)[colnames(x) == 'Long'] <- 'longitude'
  colnames(x)[colnames(x) == 'Lat'] <- 'latitude'
  x
})`
This will come out a bit odd when copied, put breaks after the first "{", "longitude" and "latitude" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put all the names of the variables inside a vector named *mynames* . But instead of this, you may use a dynamic one by using `list.files()` etc.

```
mynames <- c("data_confirmed","data_deceased","data_recovered","data_confirmed_us","data_deceased_us")

for(i in mynames) {
      var <- get(i)
      colnames(var)[grepl('Long',colnames(get(i)))] <- 'longitude'
      colnames(var)[grepl('Lat',colnames(get(i)))] <- 'latitude'
      assign(i,var)

}
```

I used `grepl` instead of `==` because there exists *Long_* instead of *Long* inside some of the data sets. So word detecting was necessary.